# Using v. Not Using the `self` Type

Tags: scala

Given the following traits:

```
scala> trait Foo { self => 
     |   def f: String = self.getClass.getName
     | }
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar { 
     |  def f: String = this.getClass.getName
     | }
defined trait Bar
```

And then making classes that extend them:

```
scala> class FooImpl extends Foo {} 
defined class FooImpl

scala> class BarImpl extends Bar {}
defined class BarImpl
```

And then calling their `f` methods on new instances:

```
scala> (new FooImpl).f
res1: String = FooImpl

scala> (new BarImpl).f
res4: String = BarImpl
```

The REPL shows that they print out the same values - the class's name.

Perhaps this isn't a good example. But what's the difference of using `self` in the above `Foo` compared to `Bar`, which uses `this`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case there's no difference—you're just using another name for `this`. Self types are useful when you need to disambiguate between different `this`s. For example:

```
abstract class Foo { self =>
  def bar: Int
  def qux = new Foo {
    def bar = self.bar
  }
}
```

If we wrote `def bar = this.bar` here, the compiler would complain that our definition of `bar` is just calling itself recursively, since the `this` would be referring to the anonymous subclass of `Foo` we're defining in `qux`, not the outside `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. `self` is just an alias for `this`. The only time it will make a difference is if you try to reference them within an inner class or trait, or object of some kind. e.g.:

```
trait Foo { self => 
    object InnerFoo {
        def f: String = self.getClass.getName
    }
}

trait Bar { 
    object InnerBar {
        def f: String = this.getClass.getName
    }
}

class FooImpl extends Foo

class BarImpl extends Bar

scala> (new FooImpl).InnerFoo.f // self still references the outer type Foo
res4: String = FooImpl

scala> (new BarImpl).InnerBar.f // this references the inner type InnerBar
res5: String = Bar$InnerBar$
```

Answer (score 2):

In the quoted case, there's basically none, as the other answers outlined.

Using a self-type mainly gives you an opportunity to further define the type of your trait's extenders, say you provide:

`self: Boing =>`

Where

```
trait Boing {
    def x
}
```

then `self.x` within `Foo` will be syntactically valid, whereas `this.x` will fail to compile.

(Note, however, that you can also refine `this` the same way, obliviating the need for an explicit self-type identifier)